# Update multiple rNVD3 charts with different data

Tags: r, shiny, nvd3.js, rcharts

I am starting out with the rCharts package, in particular using it within Shiny. However I want to take advantage of some of the functionality of the rNVD3 options. Ideally I would like to replicate some of what we can see on the [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/index.html) page, namely a single legend updates multiple plots.

I have two plots, one a time series and one a bar chart showing the totals of the time series. A minimal example is

```
library(devtools)
install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')
library(rCharts)
library(reshape)
options(gsubfn.engine = "R") #If using a Mac
library(sqldf)
set.seed(2084)
dfSales <- data.frame(month = month.abb,
                    FR = runif(12, 20, 30),
                    SP = runif(12, 60, 70),
                    UK = runif(12, 100, 110)
                    )
sales <- melt(dfSales, id = 'month')
# Adding a dummy variable name, so that we can take advantage of the grouped / stacked option in mutliBarChart.
totalSales <- sqldf("select 'TotalSales' as name, variable, sum(value) as totalSales from sales group by variable")

# Simple line chart
h1 <- hPlot(x = "month", y = "value", data = sales, type = "line", group = "variable")
h1
```

[image]

```
# Simple bar chart
n1 <- nPlot(totalSales~name, group='variable', data = totalSales, type = "multiBarChart")
n1
```

[image]

So I would like to display both on the same page of a shiny app, but have a single legend so that if I select one of the countries, then that country would disappear/reappear from both plots.

I know that I can use checkboxGroupInput in Shiny to achieve some of this, but the original data set is much larger and takes a long time to load up each time.

Is there a way to have a single legend for both plots within R?

Comment: Your bar chart doesn't appear to be working correctly.  Taking your code verbatim results in a blank image.

Comment: Is it just the bar chart that is blank (i.e. does the line chart display). I've added a couple of extra libraries which might help. Are you using the most up to date rCharts? I am using version 0.98.1091 of RStudio.

Comment: I just installed the most recent `rCharts` so it should be up to date.  The line chart does display properly.  Is that part of your problem that the bar chart isn't currently working for your data?

Comment: I've added how the two plots should look in the original question, I've had no problem producing them. What I now want to do is to have a single legend for both plots, so that 'FR', 'SP' and 'UK' are the same colours in both and if I click on one of the countries in the elgend, then that country will disappear / reappear in both plots.